# How to print something multiple times in awk

Tags: awk

I have a file `sample.txt` that looks like this:

```
Sequence: chr18_gl000207_random

Repeat 1    

    Indices: 2822--2996  Score: 135
    Period size: 36  Copynumber: 4.8  Consensus size: 36
    Consensus pattern (36 bp):   
    TCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGCAGACTGT

Repeat 2

    Indices: 2736--3623  Score: 932
    Period size: 111  Copynumber: 8.1  Consensus size: 111
    Consensus pattern (111 bp):   
    TTGTGGCAGACTGTTCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGTTGCGGGTTCAGTAGAGGTGGTA
    GTGGTGGCTGTTGTGGTTGTAGCCTCAGTGGAAGTGCCTGCAGTTG

Repeat 3

    Indices: 3421--3496  Score: 89
    Period size: 39  Copynumber: 1.9  Consensus size: 39
    Consensus pattern (39 bp):   
    AGTGCTGACTGTTGTGGTGGCAGCCTCAGTAGAAGTGGT
```

I have used `awk` to extract values for parameters that are relevant for me like this:

```
paste <(awk '/Indices/ {print $2}' sample.txt) <(awk '/Period size/ {print $3}' sample.txt) <(awk '/Copynumber/ {print $5}' sample.txt) <(awk '/Consensus pattern/ {getline; print $0}' sample.txt)
```

Output:

```
2822--2996      36      4.8     TCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGCAGACTGT
2736--3623      111     8.1     TTGTGGCAGACTGTTCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGTTGCGGGTTCAGTAGAGGTGGTA
3421--3496      39      1.9     AGTGCTGACTGTTGTGGTGGCAGCCTCAGTAGAAGTGGT
```

Now I want to add the parameter Sequence to every row.

Desired output:

```
chr18_gl000207_random:2822--2996      36      4.8     TCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGCAGACTGT
chr18_gl000207_random:2736--3623      111     8.1     TTGTGGCAGACTGTTCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGTTGCGGGTTCAGTAGAGGTGGTA
chr18_gl000207_random:3421--3496      39      1.9     AGTGCTGACTGTTGTGGTGGCAGCCTCAGTAGAAGTGGT
```

I want to do this for many files in a loop so I need a solution that would work with a different number of Repeats as well.

Comment: Please [edit] you question to show a [mcev] with concise, testable sample input and expected output. Create a minimal example that demonstrates the specific problem you want help with, don't just post whatever text you have lying around.

Comment: Hello mr. Morton, thank you for your comment. I have edited my question and hope it is more suited now.

Comment: That looks like a huge improvement.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
$1 == "Sequence:" { seq = $2; next }
$1 == "Indices:"  { ind = $2; next }
$1 == "Period"    { per = $3; cpy = $5; next }
$1 == "Consensus" { isCon=1; next }
isCon { print seq":"ind, per, cpy, $1; isCon=0 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
chr18_gl000207_random:2822--2996        36      4.8     TCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGCAGACTGT
chr18_gl000207_random:2736--3623        111     8.1     TTGTGGCAGACTGTTCAGTTGCAGTGCTGGCTGTTGTTGTGGTTGCGGGTTCAGTAGAGGTGGTA
chr18_gl000207_random:3421--3496        39      1.9     AGTGCTGACTGTTGTGGTGGCAGCCTCAGTAGAAGTGGT
```